# Expressing quantifier free $\mathcal{L}_{PA}$-formulae $\varphi(y,\vec{x})$ with polynomials

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

I'm stuck at the following exercise:

I want to show that for every quantifier-free formula in the language of $\mathsf{PA}$ there are polynomials $P(y,\vec{x}),Q(y,\vec{x})$ such that for all $\vec{n} = n_1,...,n_k \in\mathbb{N}$ it holds
\begin{align*}
\big(\mathcal{N} \models\exists y.\varphi[y,\vec{n}] \big) \Leftrightarrow \big( \exists z \in \mathbb{N}. P(z,\vec{n}) = Q(z,\vec{n}) \big),
\end{align*} 
where $\mathcal{N} \models \mathsf{PA}$ is the natural model.

I tried proceeding by induction on the complexity of $\varphi$. Of course, the base case is straightforward and I believe $\vee$ is not that hard. I didn't succeed in the induction step regarding $\neg$ however.

I think this induction step comes down to finding, for any polynomial $R(y,\vec{n})$ a polynomial $S(y,\vec{n})$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\forall \vec{n} ( \exists y. R(y,\vec{n}) \not=0 \leftrightarrow \exists z. S(z,\vec{n}) = 0).
\end{align*}

Comment: Where does this exercise come from?

Comment: @Rob, from http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/godelmoeder.pdf (Q.95), a reader about Gödel's incompleteness theorems.

Comment: My earlier answer was definitely an answer to the wrong question and I do not see how to fix it to answer your actual question. I will delete it if you unaccept it.

Comment: @Rob, done. Although it really seemed like something that could easily be fixed! To bad, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I can't see any easy fix and suspect that the exercise may not have been stated correctly. In the link you gave, it says "the following exercise gives its relevance to Hilbert's 10th problem", but the exercise is about Diophantine problems in one variable and such problems are decidable (which is what the answer I deleted was leading to).